# Views content in search results page

Tags: views, search

I have created a content type and used this in Views. Means this content type is always display via Views only . When searching for a keyword these nodes are displaying in the search result page which is fine.

When clicking on the result it opens the individual node content page but I want to open the Views page where these nodes are in use.
Please help if anybody know the solution.

Comment: finally, you got some advance?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the file `your_site/modules/search/search-result.tpl.php` to your theme and modify the code.

You can read more about this in:

[Customizing search-results.tpl.php and search-result.tpl.php](https://www.drupal.org/node/2475917)